# How to rewrite description property in NSDictionary by extension in swift?

Tags: swift, objective-c-category, swift-extensions

I want to rewrite the description property in NSDictionary by textension in swift, but can't figure how. This is very easy and common in Objective-C by using category, I can just do as this:

```
@implementation NSDictionary (Log)

- (NSString *)descriptionWithLocale:(id)locale
{
    NSMutableString *retStr = [NSMutableString string];

    retStr = ...

    return [retStr copy];
}

@end
```

I tried in swift as:

```
extension NSDictionary {
    override public var description: String {
        get {
            return ...
        }
    }
}
```

But I failed because:

```
Method 'description()' with Objective-C selector 'description' conflicts with getter for 'description' with the same Objective-C selector
```

Then I don't know what should I do. Please help me ~.~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extensions can add new functionality to a type, but they cannot override existing functionality.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html

Comment: Also in Objective-C you should "Avoid Category Method Name Clashes" - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html

Comment: I see. So I should avoid making the "clashing method name category" in Objective-C, although the code may work under current implementation. And in swift, this should-be-avoided feature no longer exists anymore.Thank you!

Comment: Yes, exactly. I fixed the link in the answer to be Swift specific.